# How to use a variable from urlSession from another class

Tags: ios, swift4, progress, urlsession

I am trying to download multiple files sequentially using urlSession.

I have this code that is in an extension in a different class. I would like to be able to use the variable progress in the viewcontroller class in order to use it to show the download progression on the screen.

How can I pass this variable from an extension from a different class into the viewcontroller class??

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

    let progress = Double(totalBytesWritten) / Double(totalBytesExpectedToWrite) * 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throw away your `progress` variable. The URLSessionDownloadTask itself vends a `progress` object (of the Progress class). It is made to solve *exactly* this sort of problem, because a Progress object is observable from anywhere (or it can be assigned to a UIProgressView's `observedProgress` directly). Just research the Progress class and it will be clear what to do.